# How to keep a test branch in sync with master and have a feature branch that merges to both

Tags: git, workflow, git-branch

I have three branches:

- master
- bug-fix
- local-test-environment (exists locally only)

master and bug-fix exist in both local and remote repos.

**Requirements:**

a) I want to keep local-test-environment in sync with master, the only difference being the local config that must not appear on the remote server as it contains authentication secrets. (I currently have the local config changes committed on local-test-environment (which is a local only branch))

b) I want to do work on local-test-environment but commit and push that to the remote server via the bug-fix branch.

c) I want to merge from the bug-fix-branch to master.

Once the bug is fixed, ideally I want to clear out the working directory from local-test-environment but bring in the big-fix before the next pece of work, by merging it in from master. This is to ensure local-test-environment is identical to master except for the test config.

I'm trying to figure out the best work flow for this.

Currently I'm making changes in the working directory of local-test-environment, then stashing them and applying them to the bug-fix branch where I commit and push them. I then go back to local-test-environment and stash apply to get them back on there and continue working.
The problem with this workflow is that I can only really do that once, otherwise next time I stash and go to bug-fix-branch, the stash will contain more than I need.

**Options**

I could git stash apply to both bug-fix-branch and local-test-environment and commit to both. The commits will be identical. However will I then be able to pull in changes from master to local-test-environment or will git view the identical but independent commits as conflicts?

Alternatively I could commit on bug-fix-branch then cherry pick from bug-fix-branch to local-test-environment. Will I then get a problem if I merge from bug-fix to master, and then from master to local-test-environment? Will git work out that the cherry picked parts that exist both in master and local-test-environment are the same and ignore them? Or will I get conflicts?

If neither of these work flows will work, is there a better one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind! I think I've just solved it. I'll just commit on both bug-fix and local-test-environment and then once I've merged bug-fix into master, delete all the commits from local-test-environment with a reset or rebase and then merge from master to local-test-environment. Seems obvious now.